# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForDebug'

Tags: android

Well I tried to shrink the code and resources as well but after running I am getting this error :

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForDebug'.
>
> > Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them.

Then I saw somewhere in the post that I should **update** my studio then I did that by downloading and installing patches. It started and I received this error :

> Error:svn: E200005: 'is not under version control

Well within few seconds I got alert message to update gradle I did that and this svn error is **gone**.

But when I run my application the first problem still **persists** and don't know how to resolve it.
If anyone got a solution please explain me ***what*** to do? and ***why*** it happened?

Comment: I am really afraid of this gradle dependencies and buildtype, don't know which one will support which?

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: @VikashKumarVerma follow the link i have opened issue and my last comment is the solution https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231947